# Boolean function returning undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, firebase, boolean, react-native

I currently am using data stored in Firebase to check if a user-submitted solution is correct. This involves me calling the function `getSolutionAndCompare` when the user presses a “submit” button. However, for some reason, although `checkSolution` is returning true to `getSolutionAndCompare`, when I call `getSolutionAndCompare` in `onSubmitPressed`, it evaluates as undefined. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Relevant code:

```
onSubmitPressed: function() {
    var output = this.getSolutionAndCompare();
    console.log('output ' + output); //this is returning undefined
    if (this.getSolutionAndCompare()) {
        Alert.alert(
            'Correct',
            "Woohoo!"
        );
    }
    else {
        Alert.alert(
            'Incorrect Submission',
            'Try again!',
        );
    }
},

getSolutionAndCompare: function() {
    var databaseSolution;
    solutionsRef.orderByChild('question_id').equalTo(Number(this.props.questionId)).once('value', (snap) => {
        var solution = snap.val();
        for (var key in solution) {
            databaseSolution = solution[key].solution;
        }
        return this.checkSolution(databaseSolution); //checkSolution returns true here
    });

},

checkSolution: function(databaseSolution) {
    if (this.state.submission == databaseSolution) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
},
```

Comment: What kind of data are you expecting to be in held in `solution` here? `var solution = snap.val()`? You go on to iterate over the `solution` object but you're only checking the final value in your return statement. Edit - that return statement doesn't appear to be returning the `getSolutionAndCompare` method so that method returns `undefined`

Comment: `solutionsRef.orderByChild('question_id').equalTo(Number(this.props.questionId)).once('value', (snap) => {` -- is this an async call? Either way, you are returning inside of an inner function, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getSolutionAndCompare` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined` because that is the default.

(The anonymous arrow function you declare inside `getSolutionAndCompare` has a return statement, but that looks [asyncronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) so you can't return its value).